# Python FLOWCHART : Program that reads information about X people, and calculate the average age in both groups, "FEMALE/MALE"

Tags: python

My code is working, but i want to understand it deeper. I would like to hear something that is good about this program i created, and something about how the program could be improved

My task is :
Write a program that reads information about a number of people, and calculates the average age of women and men in the group.

I want to explain and learn :
Document and evaluate the process and reflect on what i can learn from it for future programming tasks.
i would like some example..

I need to reflect on how it could be further developed.
How could this be further developed?

The more different situations a program can handle, the more *robust* it is, i believe this is a word i need understand deeper
How can i think here? Robustness,
My understanding in robustness.. = Code is robust if it tends to behave in a useful, controlled way, even when things go wrong pretty much?

I would like to hear something that is good about this program i created, and something about how the program could be improved.

Ps my written code atm :

```
from statistics import mean

lookup_list = {
    "m": [],
    "f": []
}

while True:

    sex = input("Enter gender (M / F) or Q to quit: ").lower()

    if sex == "q":
        break

    if not sex in lookup_list:
        continue

    age = int(input("Enter your age : "))

    lookup_list[sex].append(age)

if len(lookup_list["m"]):
    print("Mean age for male: %0.1f" % mean(lookup_list["m"]))

if len(lookup_list["f"]):
    print("Mean age for female: %0.1f" % mean(lookup_list["f"]))
```

Answer (score 1):

The code looks fairly good to me.

Some things I might change would be to use 2 lists. 1 for male and 1 for female and a set for the check of user input of the sex not being male or female.

You are close on what `robust` should mean. `Robust` could should be code that does excellent for the given problem. In your case, you could consider user validation of user input.